# Gitlab CI CD only run Pipeline Step when certain criteria is met

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to configure my CI/CD pipeline so that a certain step is only executed if some conditions are met.

My current rule definition looks like this:

```
 rules:
    - if: '($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" '
      exists:
        - $MY_FILE
```

What I want to achieve:

1. Execute step only if a merge from branch_x was done into develop
2. **Or** Execute step when pipeline triggered over the GitLab UI
3. **Or** Execute step if a commit is pushed directly to develop
4. **And** the file in `$MY_FILE` is present in the repository

Other than expected, the step gets **not** executed on

1. Push
2. Merge Branch_X into develop
3. Manually trigger over GitLab UI

The corresponding file exists within the repository.

The step work is if I change back to

```
  only:
    - develop
```

But then I can not set the condition that the file needs to be present.

Comment: When you said "manually trigger over Gitlab UI" do you mean "hit the play button for a job that has `when: manual`", an actual "trigger", or the "Run Pipeline" button? They are different things that have different values for the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable.

Comment: I mean the Run Pipeline button. But that is not the important case. Would be enough if it would work on merge on develop or on a new push on develop. But neither nor does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the issue you're running into is that some Predefined Variables only exist in certain types of pipelines. For example, the `CI_COMMIT_TAG` variable, which would hold the name of a tag, only exists if the pipeline is a "Tag pipeline" (ran after a tag is created). However, if a tag points to a commit that is the HEAD of a branch that is the Source of a Merge Request, it is still just a Tag pipeline, so none of the Merge Request specific variables will exist.

Due to this, your conditional will get slightly more complex since we'll need some more parenthesis, or more `if` clauses for our `rules` section:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push' || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'web') && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'develop'
    exists:
      - $MY_FILE
    when: always
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'develop'
    exists:
      - $MY_FILE
    when: always
  - when: never
```

**Note:** you could write this using only one `if` clause and just use more parenthesis.

Let's look at these changes one by one.

First, the `push` and `web` pipeline sources are more or less identical in terms of how the pipeline is ran, and which Predefined Variables are available.

Second, the variable `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is only available in certain pipelines. Most noticeably, it only exists when there is a Branch. If the pipeline runs for a tag, the variable will not exist, it's not just empty. If it's a merge request event, the variable will not exist. `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is more reliable, even though it can have more values (Commit SHAs, Branch names, or Tag names).

Third, the `merge_request_event` source is a totally different animal compared to the other sources we're dealing with here. The Predefined Variables available are totally different since there are now two branches (the source and the target). Also, a merge_request_event pipeline can only ever run if you have `rules` in your pipeline definition for merge_request_event's.

I ran some tests with this rules scenario, with this pipeline definition:

```yaml
stages:
  - run

Run Job:
  stage: run
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME

Second Run Job:
  stage: run
  image: alpine:latest
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push' || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'web') && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'develop'
      exists:
        - 'a_file'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == 'new_branch'
      exists:
        - 'a_file'
      when: always
    - when: never  
  script:
    - echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
```

Here's the job output for a normal `Push` event to a branch other than `develop`:

```sh
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
push
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
other_branch
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
other_branch
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
```

Note: only the first job runs since the branch isn't `develop`. If the branch is `develop` **and** `a_file` exists, both jobs run, and the output is identical.

Here's the output of a job with the 'web' source, to a branch other than `develop`:

```sh
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
web
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
other_branch
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
other_branch
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
```

Again, in this case there is only one job in the pipeline. If instead we hit Run Pipeline for the `develop` branch and `a_file` exists, we run both jobs and the output is identical:

```sh
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
web
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
develop
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
develop
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
```

Lastly, if we push to a branch that's the `source` of a merge request targeting `develop` with `a_file` in the repository, we get the `merge_request_event`, but only get the second job due to the way Merge Request Pipelines work:

```sh
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
merge_request_event
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
some_other_branch
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
some_other_branch
$ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
new_branch
```

Here's the documentation for [Merge Request Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, so my approach was not bad at all. But it seems like there is something faulty with `exists $MY_FILE`. Seems like the variable does not get resolved. If I use `exists filename.txt` for example, it works like expected.

Further, I face the issue that a detached pipeline for this step is run when the branch gets merged. Something I'll need to investigate and fix.

Comment: It might depend on where you're declaring the variable. If it's within the pipeline, it won't work for any `rules` definition since the `rules` are ran/determined before the pipeline starts, so it would be referencing a variable that doesn't yet exist.